# Email Cross browser and cross client bugs

Tags: email, newsletter

I'm creating an email template for a client.  There are so many small bugs.

I can't get the side images to line up without having space between them and the tables width won't match up.

Check out the cross client previews here:
[removed]

and here is my code:

```
<table width="600" bgcolor="000000" style="padding-left: 14xpx;">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding: 5px 0 0 0;margin-bottom: 0;">
            <ul  style="padding:0;">
                <li style="list-style: none;">
                    <span><a href="#" style="border: none !imporant;"><img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/left-img-01.jpg" alt=" Join Executive Chef Massimo Bebber" style="margin-bottom: -4px !important;"/></a></span></li>
                <li style="list-style: none;"><span><a href="#" style="border: none !imporant;"><img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/left-img-02.jpg" alt=" Join Executive Chef Massimo Bebber" style="margin-bottom: -4px !important;"/></a></span><singleline /></li>
                <li style="list-style: none;"><span><a href="#" style="border: none !imporant;"><img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/left-img-03.jpg" alt=" Join Executive Chef Massimo Bebber" style="margin-bottom: -4px !important;"/></a></span></li>
            </ul>
        </td>

        <td align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding: 10px 0 0 0; position: relative; left: -5px;">
            <span>
                <a href="http://siriony.com/sample-page/chef-massimo-bebber/" style="border: none !imporant;">
                    <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/chef-massimo-bebber.jpg" alt-"Sirio Chef" /></a>
            </span>
        </td>

        <td align="left">
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/sirio-thumbnails.png" alt="Sirio Ristorante" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="605" bgcolor="000000" style="margin-top: -20px;">
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/lines.gif" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="606" bgcolor="000000" style="">
    <tr>
       <td align="left"> <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-01.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-02.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-03.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-04.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-05.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-06.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
           </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more information.  Your link shows many different views.  Which one is considered accurate?

Comment: Scratch that.  This code is really bad.  negative margins? negative positioning?  Tags that don't exist (`<singleline />`???)  and no clear reason why you chopped up the image to begin with.

Comment: @ChrisLivelyI actually know html very well just have never used tables. And lol that <Singleline/> is from campaignmanager.com where I was sending test emails, wouldnt let me send without it. The image is going to be three links thats why I chopped it. The space between the man and the three just images needs to be removed. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Singleline is a Campaign Monitor tag that they use to insert content into their [email template editor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problems in what you posted it's hard to tell exactly what it is you were trying to do.

The following is meant to be harsh:

First off, get everything laid out in the right spot before you start randomly adding negative positioning styles; there was no reason for that.  Second, you might want to pick up a book on html and css before you take on another client.  You have quite a bit to learn.  Pay attention to text layout, image alignment and cell positioning.

The following gets rid of most of the garbage.

```
<table width="600" bgcolor="000000" style="padding-left: 14px;">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/left-img-01.jpg" alt=" Join Executive Chef Massimo Bebber" style="border:0px;margin:0px;" /><br />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/left-img-02.jpg" alt=" Join Executive Chef Massimo Bebber" style="border:0px;margin:0px;"/><br />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/left-img-03.jpg" alt=" Join Executive Chef Massimo Bebber" style="border:0px;margin:0px;"/>
        </td>

        <td align="left" valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
            <span>
                <a href="http://siriony.com/sample-page/chef-massimo-bebber/" style="border: none !imporant;"><img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/chef-massimo-bebber.jpg" alt-"Sirio Chef"  style="border:0px;" /></a>
            </span>
        </td>

        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/sirio-thumbnails.png" alt="Sirio Ristorante" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" colspan="3"><img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/lines.gif" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="left" valign="top" colspan="3"> <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-01.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-02.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-03.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-04.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-05.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
            <img src="http://www.kieshajewel.com/sirio/footer-06.gif" alt="Reserve Now" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks! I still need a few more changes. Can you help? You seem a bit angry :/

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time there are spaces between images, it is because people forget `display:block;` on the image tags. In this case though, you are floating your images, which is the rare case where display block is not needed. I wouldn't recommend this technique in html email however, unless there is a lot of spare room, as different clients have slightly different spacing between images.

Put each of your images in their own table cell, and it should fix the problems:

```
<td width="">
  <img  alt="" src="" width="" height="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
</td>
```

If you still have issues, repost your code and I'll take another look at that point.

Comment: if you can remove the space in the picture of the chef that would be great. I'm using Chris' code above.

Comment: Don't use Chris' code. You can use it as a clean start, but separate your images into their own td's so they are not floating in the same one.